# If copper becomes copper oxides because of oxygen in the air, is it a competing reaction?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

If copper becomes copper oxides because of oxygen in the air, is it a competing reaction?

My science class made pure copper with a simple displacement reaction. We let it set on the window to let it dry then 2 days later it became green.

Answer (score 1):

Green isn't due to an copper oxide but rather copper(II) carbonate-hydroxide, $\ce{Cu2CO3(OH)2}$. The mineral is known as malachite.